# iPhone 5 Lightning to USB Cable - Is it safe to use replicas?

Tags: hardware, hardware-recommendation, iphone, charging

I need to buy a [Lightning to USB cable](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD818ZM/A/lightning-to-usb-cable?fnode=45) for my iPhone 5.

In eBay you can find replicas for one third of the price. **Do you know if these can ruin your phone?** If I use an original power adapter, a counterfeit USB cable will have any impact?

Comment: Although these clearly are not duplicate, It would be best for the site to have both narrow versions of the same question consolidated.